# Dictionary of tensors input for Keras Functional API TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a dataset of dictionary of tensors, and the following model defined using the  subclassing API:

```
class Model(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self._movie_full_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
        units=40, activation=tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu"))
    self._user_full_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
        units=40, activation=tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu"))
    self._full_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
        units=1, activation=tf.keras.layers.Activation("sigmoid"))

  def call(self, features):
    movie_embedding = self._movie_full_dense(features['movie'])
    user_embedding = self._user_full_dense(features['user'])
    combined = tf.concat([movie_embedding, user_embedding], 1)
    output = self._full_dense(combined)
    return output
```

I want to implement it using the functional API. but I do not know how to define the inputs? Namely, what is the functional equivalent for the following?

```
self._movie_full_dense(features['movie'])
```

Answer (score 7):

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.version.VERSION)

toy_data = {'movie': [[0], [1], [0], [1]], 'user': [[10], [12], [12], [10]]}
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(toy_data).batch(2)

for x in dataset:
    print(x)

def make_model():
    inp_movie = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,))
    inp_user = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,))
    movie_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            units=40, activation=tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu"))(inp_movie)
    user_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            units=40, activation=tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu"))(inp_user)
    combined = tf.concat([movie_embedding, user_embedding], 1)
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            units=1, activation=tf.keras.layers.Activation("sigmoid"))(combined)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inp_movie, inp_user], outputs=output)
    return model

model = make_model()

for x in dataset:
    print(model(x))
```

This works. Beware that the iterable you pass to the `inputs` argument of the `tf.keras.Model` call has to be sorted in the same order as the dictionary you will use, which is sorted by its keys, `movie` then `user`. So using `inputs={'a': inp_movie, 'b': inp_user}` or `inputs={'movie': inp_movie, 'user': inp_user}` also works, while `inputs=[inp_user, inp_movie]` won't.

You can use this code to test this kind of interaction:

```
def make_test_model():
    inp_movie = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,))
    inp_user = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,))
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs={'a': inp_movie, 'b': inp_user}, outputs=inp_movie)
    return model

def make_test_model_2():
    inp_movie = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,))
    inp_user = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,))
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inp_user, inp_movie], outputs=inp_movie)
    return model

model_test = make_test_model()
model_test_2 = make_test_model_2()

for x in dataset:
    print(model_test(x))
for x in dataset:
    print(model_test_2(x))
```

You can also name the `Input` layers using the keys of your dictonary, and give as the `inputs` argument a list of `Input` layers sorted by the layers names. This allows you to add or remove inputs in your model without having to worry about rewriting your `inputs` argument each time. So this is what I would do:

```
def make_model_2():
    input_list = []
    inp_movie = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name='movie')
    input_list.append(inp_movie)
    inp_user = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name='user')
    input_list.append(inp_user)
    movie_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            units=40, activation=tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu"))(inp_movie)
    user_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            units=40, activation=tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu"))(inp_user)
    combined = tf.concat([movie_embedding, user_embedding], 1)
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            units=1, activation=tf.keras.layers.Activation("sigmoid"))(combined)
    input_list.sort(key=lambda inp: inp._keras_history.layer.name)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_list, outputs=output)
    return model
```

Here is a way to test that it works:

```
def make_test_model_3(boolean):
    input_list = []
    inp_movie = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name='movie')
    inp_user = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name='user')
    if boolean:
        input_list.append(inp_movie)
        input_list.append(inp_user)
    else:
        input_list.append(inp_user)
        input_list.append(inp_movie)
    input_list.sort(key=lambda inp: inp._keras_history.layer.name)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_list, outputs=inp_movie)
    return model

model_test_3_0= make_test_model_3(True)
model_test_3_1= make_test_model_3(False)

for x in dataset:
    print(model_test_3_0(x))
for x in dataset:
    print(model_test_3_1(x))
```

**Edit 2020-02-20:**

`make_model` does not work with tf2.1.0, but `make_model_2` still does. I have oppened an issue on GitHub about this backward incompatibility. [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36933) is the link if you are interested. Recall that both functions work if you plan to stay on tf2.0.0.